# Which statistical test would be most appropriate? Chi-Squared or something else?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

My data is essentially:

[image]

Var_A and Var_B are treatments assigned to the id and Var_C is the outcome.

The id's are randomly assigned treatments so that , for example, 40% get Var_A only, 30% get Var_A and Var_B, 20% get Var_B only, and 10% get neither Var_A nor Var_B.

I'm wanting to evaluate the proportion of Var_C that is Yes compared to the total for each treatment plan.

Right now I've got tables like the following:

[image]

My initial thoughts are to use a chi-square test, but I'm not sure if that's the most appropriate.

Comment: As I see it, you can arrange the results in a 2x2 table, with the values being frequencies of the variable C. In that case a Chi-square test would work. Also possible is a logistic regression model.

Comment: @user2974951 I thought Chi-Square test too, but I wasn't positive there wasn't some other test I couldn't think of that would fit better.

Comment: As I mentioned, you could also use a logistic regression, which would allow you more freedom in the model / hypotheses specification.